# How Do I separate data written in the same column?

Tags: excel, matlab, col

So I've got bunch of file in excel that has the measure of the electric current versus voltage with like 2000 points. The problem is, they're all saved in the column same box. It's suppose to be such that Column A has all the voltages and Column B all the currents. Right now, everything is saved in Column A both voltages and current.

I really don't want to separate 2000 points with 20 files of it hand by hand, is there a good way to separate them? The good news is, the points are separated by a space e.g. [1.001 2.002] with 1.001 being a voltage or 2.002 being a current or separated by a negative sign if there is one [-1.001-2.002] so I feel like a simple program can fix this up. I know how to code in C and matlab(also, the goal is to make it matlab readable) but what's the best way to resolve this if it could also be done maybe in excel macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on a unix/linux?

Save the file as CSV.

Run this from the terminal.

```
$ sed -i .bak "s/ /,/g" my-file.csv
```

Your original file will be saved as my-file.bak. The my-file.csv will now be comma delimited instead of space delineated.

Open the CSV in excel.

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned but the original files were on google drive, as excel. When I opened them with google sheets and saved it as csv like part of your suggestion, it almost worked! The only problem is in the case when the second value is preceded by negative sign, e.g. [1.01 -2.02] excel mistake it as a formula 1.01 minus 2.02 and the whole cell becomes NaN. Will the command above on Unix resolve this problem? I'm currently on windows but I can go find a machine with Unix installed to do it, or mac.

Comment: The above process removes spaces and replaces with commas. There are many ways todo that however. For instance here: http://textmechanic.com/Find-and-Replace-Text.html. Open the csv in notepad and paste into that site.

Comment: Ok, but it seems like saving the excel format into .csv form already automatically interpret the cell section as an equation and turns it into NaN when saved into .csv format, so I guess it's more of an Excel problem's at this point. But thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to open the sheet in Power Query and split the column based on a delimiter. Assuming you have something (a space, comma, etc.), then this will give you two new columns. In Query Editor, go to split column and then by delimiter. Source: https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Split-a-column-of-text-Power-Query-5282d425-6dd0-46ca-95bf-8e0da9539662?ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU#__toc354843578

Edit: If you don't have Power Query, it's a free add-on for Excel: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39379